# Getting windows to allocate more memory to python

Tags: python, windows

I'm using python2.7 (I think it's the 32bit version, not sure how check that) and windows 10. I've implemented a neural net to classify some images. I have a data set of 25000, but I get a memory error from python if I try to load all of them at once into my training set(using PIL). I know my computer has enough RAM to do this task though because in the task manager, I can see that windows is only allocating a maximum of 1GB to python, even tho I have 8gb free (and 16gb total).

How can I tell windows to allow Python more memory?

As an auxiliary question, one reason I'm having memory error is that I'm using mini-batch gradient descent to train my algorithm. In the course of doing that, I create shuffled versions of the training data so that I can draw from them without replacement (as opposed to just shuffling my training data from the get go and then randomly picking out mini batches with replacement). I heard that drawing without replacement is the correct way to go, but the requirement that I create shuffled versions of my data means I have to use up double the amount of memory keeping both sets around.

The code I use to create my mini batches is: (X is input data, Y is labels)

```
    Xbatch = np.array((X.shape[0],batch))
    Ybatch = np.array((Y.shape[0],batch))
    permutation = list(np.random.permutation(Y.shape[1]))
    shuffled_X = X[:, permutation]
    shuffled_Y = Y[:, permutation].reshape((1,Y.shape[1]))
    Xbatch = shuffled_X[:,b*batch:(b*batch+batch)]
    Ybatch = shuffled_Y[:,b*batch:(b*batch+batch)]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this without doubling my memory use?

Comment: Are you running your program in an IDE or from console?

Comment: I am running it from the command prompt.

Comment: There may only be 1 GiB of committed memory, but there can be additional reservations of the process address space, which for 32-bit Python is 2 GiB. It's possible for a 32-bit executable to be linked as large-address aware to get up to 4 GiB of address space, but I wouldn't fiddle with that. Just switch to 64-bit Python.

Comment: Do you know what the max memory usage for 64 bit python would be then? As of right now, I can only open 2500 images before I get a memory error.

Comment: A 64-bit process can address up to 128 TiB in Windows 8.1 and later.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.